# notepad++ replacing parantheses with brackets

Tags: regex, matlab, notepad++, julia

I am converting a code of mine from MATLAB to julia, thus I need to replace parentheses used for indexing: they are of the type `()` in MATLAB and of the type `[]` in julia. Functions parentheses are of the same type in both, i.e. `()`.
I thought that the fastest way to do this was to use Notepad++, finding all of the parenthes and then replacing them with brackets when need.
Anyhow it does not work as expected.

I won't copy all of the function I am converting now, but some parts as example:

```
x= coord(:,1);
y= coord(:,2);

natG_coord(1,1)=  sqrt(1/3);
natG_coord(2,1)= -sqrt(1/3);
natG_coord(3,1)= -sqrt(1/3);
natG_coord(4,1)=  sqrt(1/3);

for i=1:4
    dNG(1,i)=  (1+etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1+etaG(i))/2 - (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2)/4;
    dNG(2,i)= -(1+etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1+etaG(i))/2 + (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2)/4;
    dNG(3,i)= -(1-etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i))/2 + (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2)/4;
    dNG(4,i)=  (1-etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i))/2 - (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2)/4;
end
```

I tried finding `\((.*)\)` and replacing with `[$1]`, but it does not get all of the parentheses. For instance, it gets the ones in declaring `x` and `y`, the `sqrt` value but does not get the `natG_coord` indexes. In the `for` cycle, it only gets the last expression of each line, i.e. `(1-etaG(i)^2)`, but the external parenthes, not the `etaG` index (which is actually what I need to replace).

I cannot see a pattern in the choice and thus cannot come up with a solution.
Other solutions not to get mad doing this parenthesis by parenthesis is fine! 
Thank you all for your help.

**edit** 
@stribizhev: the final result should be this:

```
x= coord[:,1]
y= coord[:,2]

natG_coord[1,1]=  sqrt(1/3)
natG_coord[2,1]= -sqrt(1/3)
natG_coord[3,1]= -sqrt(1/3)
natG_coord[4,1]=  sqrt(1/3)

for i=1:4
  dNG[1,i]=  (1+etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1+etaG[i])/2 - (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4
  dNG[2,i]= -(1+etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1+etaG[i])/2 + (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4
  dNG[3,i]= -(1-etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i])/2 + (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4
  dNG[4,i]=  (1-etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i])/2 - (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4
end
```

What I get finding `\((.*)\)` and replacing with `[$1]` one time is:

```
x= coord[:,1];
y= coord[:,2];

natG_coord[1,1)=  sqrt(1/3];
natG_coord[2,1)= -sqrt(1/3];
natG_coord[3,1)= -sqrt(1/3];
natG_coord[4,1)=  sqrt(1/3];

for i=1:4
    dNG[1,i)=  (1+etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1+etaG(i))/2 - (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
    dNG[2,i)= -(1+etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1+etaG(i))/2 + (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
    dNG[3,i)= -(1-etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i))/2 + (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
    dNG[4,i)=  (1-etaG(i))/4 + csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i))/2 - (1-etaG(i)^2)/4 - 2*csiG(i)*(1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
end
```

What I get finding `\(((?>[^()]|(?R))*)\)` and replacing all with `[$1]` one time is (I know you said several times, if I do it it'll replace every matching braces in the end):

```
x= coord[:,1];
y= coord[:,2];

natG_coord[1,1]=  sqrt[1/3];
natG_coord[2,1]= -sqrt[1/3];
natG_coord[3,1]= -sqrt[1/3];
natG_coord[4,1]=  sqrt[1/3];

for i=1:4
    dNG[1,i]=  [1+etaG(i)]/4 + csiG[i]*[1+etaG(i)]/2 - [1-etaG(i)^2]/4 - 2*csiG[i]*[1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
    dNG[2,i]= -[1+etaG(i)]/4 + csiG[i]*[1+etaG(i)]/2 + [1-etaG(i)^2]/4 - 2*csiG[i]*[1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
    dNG[3,i]= -[1-etaG(i)]/4 + csiG[i]*[1-etaG(i)]/2 + [1-etaG(i)^2]/4 - 2*csiG[i]*[1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
    dNG[4,i]=  [1-etaG(i)]/4 + csiG[i]*[1-etaG(i)]/2 - [1-etaG(i)^2]/4 - 2*csiG[i]*[1-etaG(i)^2]/4;
end
```

What I get finding `\(([^()]*)\)` replacing all with `[$1]` one time is:

```
x= coord[:,1];
y= coord[:,2];

natG_coord[1,1]=  sqrt[1/3];
natG_coord[2,1]= -sqrt[1/3];
natG_coord[3,1]= -sqrt[1/3];
natG_coord[4,1]=  sqrt[1/3];

for i=1:4
    dNG[1,i]=  (1+etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1+etaG[i])/2 - (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4;
    dNG[2,i]= -(1+etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1+etaG[i])/2 + (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4;
    dNG[3,i]= -(1-etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i])/2 + (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4;
    dNG[4,i]=  (1-etaG[i])/4 + csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i])/2 - (1-etaG[i]^2)/4 - 2*csiG[i]*(1-etaG[i]^2)/4;
end
```

So the last one is exactly what I was looking for. Once I go with the "find next" command, I can decide whether they are indexing parantheses or not and substitute them or not (avoiding the `sqrt` function input, for instance). 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are your really sure you need to bother to check for matching parentheses? Doing two plaintext replace looks like it would be much easier, and shouldn't pose problem if the input code is functional. That is, when the parentheses is actual code (rather than a string, for example).

Comment: Aaron is right if all the `(` and `)` outside of some quoted strings should be turned into `[` and `]`. Besides, try `\(((?>[^()]|(?R))*)\)` and replace with `[$1]` (hit *Replace All* several times).

Comment: @myGatz: Any feedback? Could you post what your expected output should look like? `(1+etaG(i))` -> `(1+etaG[i])`? Try then `\(([^()]*)\)`. See https://regex101.com/r/wG6zC3/1. Or even `(\w+)\(([^()]*)\)` -> `$1[$2]`. See  https://regex101.com/r/wG6zC3/2

Comment: Have you considered a tool such as https://github.com/lakras/matlab-to-julia ?

Comment: @Aaron: checking for matching parentheses allow me to spare time; I'd need half the time replacing two parentheses at once

Comment: @myGatz the thing is that if you do it in two steps, you have a simple mapping : `[` corresponds to `(`, and `]` to `)` ; while if you want to replace both at the same time, you have to check which parentheses you have matched to know which caret is appropriate, which is a hassle. If you can use GNU tools I'd recommend the command `sed -e 's/(/[/g' -e 's/)/]/g'` which disregards parenthesis coupling but does both replacement at the same time as per your request.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thank you very much for your help, it is what I was looking for. It is not an answer so I cannot vote it, but I would if you re-post it as answer.

Comment: @Aaron: I'm sorry, I do not understand how to apply what you are suggesting. stribizhev tip is more straightforward to me. Thank you for you help too.

Comment: No problem, if stribizhev's solution work, go for it. I'm just saying using regular expressions to replace two characters by two others is overkill, but if you're more familiar with this tool it might still be better for you.

Comment: @mareoraft: I have no knowledge of java nor Perl. Moreover I wanted to get my hands on julia. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, just a sec, I will post all the suggestions with explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `\(([^()]*)\)` (to replace with `[$1]`) worked for you, here is the explanation:

```
\(([^()]*)\)
```

Matches:

- `\(` - an opening round bracket
- `([^()]*)` - Capture group 1 matches zero or more characters other than `(` and `)` (with `[^()]*`)
- `\)`- a closing round bracket

**This regex above will match all last nested level parentheses, that do not have any parentheses inside them**.

Answering Aaron's remark about replacing the parentheses inside the quoted strings, it is great that Notepad++ supports Boost conditional replacement patterns. We can *match* what we do not need to modify and replace with self, and use another replacement for the other matches.

```
(?<o1>"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|(?<o2>\(([^()]*)\))
```

And replace with `(?{o1}$+{o1}:[$3])`.

Note that `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` matches C strings with escaped entities correctly and efficiently. The replacement pattern means to replace with the quoted string (if `o1` group matched) or with `[`+Group 3 value+`]` (if the other group matched).

If you need to replace outer balanced parentheses, use

```
\(((?>[^()]|(?R))*)\)
```

And replace with `[$1]` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK9aU1/2)). If you need to replace the overlapping parenthetical substrings, you will need to hit *Replace All* several times.

*Regex explanation*:

```
\(            # an outer literal opening round bracket
   (          #  start group 1
     (?>      #   start of atomic group
       [^()]  #     any character other than ( and )
       |      #    OR
       (?R)   #     recursively match the whole pattern
     )*       #   end atomic group and repeat zero or more times
   )          #  end of group 1
\)            #   match a literal closing round bracket
```

If the strings you need to replace those parentheses should be preceded with word characters, use

```
(\w+)(\(((?>[^()]|(?2))*)\))
```

And replace with `$1[$3]`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK9aU1/1)

This regex uses a `(?2)` [subroutine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#balanced) that just *repeats* the second capture group subpattern.

Now, avoiding to match these inside quoted strings. Assume we have `var d = "r(string here)"` and we do not want to turn the `()` to `[]` here. Instead of `(\w+)(\(((?>[^()]|(?2))*)\))` (with `$1[$3]` replacement), use

```
(?<o1>"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|(?<o2>(\w+)(\(((?>[^()]|(?4))*)\)))
```

And `(?{o1}$+{o1}:$3[$5])` as the replacement. This will keep `var d = "r(string here)"` string intact, and will turn `var f = a(fg()g)` into `var f = a[fg()g]`.

[image]

Comment: It might be interesting to mention that it will also replace parentheses that are inside strings. I'm don't think it's worth it to modify the regex so that it doesn't match them, but people using it should be aware of this side-effect.

Comment: Well, I hope I have given a sufficient explanation. Please check.

Comment: If that isn't enough I don't know what will be ! Thanks for making me found out Boost !